# Multiplying multiple columns with each other into a new dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to multiply many of my binary variables into new columns, so called interactive variables. My dataset is structured like this:

```
YearCountry <- data.frame( Time = c("2000","2001", "2002", "2003",
                           "2000","2001", "2002", "2003",
                           "2000","2001", "2002", "2003"),
                  AL = c(1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                  FR = c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0),
                  UK = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1),
                  Y2000d = c(1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0),
                  Y2001d = c(0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0),
                  Y2002d = c(0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0),
                  Y2003d = c(0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1))
YearCountry

 Time AL FR UK Y2000d Y2001d Y2002d Y2003d
1  2000  1  0  0      1      0      0      0
2  2001  1  0  0      0      1      0      0
3  2002  1  0  0      0      0      1      0
4  2003  1  0  0      0      0      0      1
5  2000  0  1  0      1      0      0      0
6  2001  0  1  0      0      1      0      0
7  2002  0  1  0      0      0      1      0
8  2003  0  1  0      0      0      0      1
9  2000  0  0  1      1      0      0      0
10 2001  0  0  1      0      1      0      0
11 2002  0  0  1      0      0      1      0
12 2003  0  0  1      0      0      0      1
```

I need to multiply the binary variable for each of the countries (AL,FR,UK) with each of the binary variables for a given year so that I get #country x #year new variables. In this case I have three countries and four years which gives 12 new variables. My full data contains 105 countries/regions and stretches over twenty years. I therefore need a general formula. I want data that looks like this

```
Interact <- data.frame(Time = c("2000","2001", "2002", "2003",
                                "2000","2001", "2002", "2003",
                                "2000","2001", "2002", "2003"),
                       Y2000xAL = c(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
            Y2001xAL = c(0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
            Y2002xAL = c(0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
            Y2003xAL = c(0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
            Y2000xFR = c(0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
            Y2001xFR = c(0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0),
            Y2002xFR = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0),
            Y2003xFR = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0),
            Y2000xUk = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0),
            Y2001xUK = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0),
            Y2002xUK = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0),
            Y2003xUK = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1))
Interact 

 Time Y2000xAL Y2001xAL Y2002xAL Y2003xAL Y2000xFR Y2001xFR Y2002xFR Y2003xFR Y2000xUk Y2001xUK Y2002xUK Y2003xUK
1  2000        1        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0
2  2001        0        1        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0
3  2002        0        0        1        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0
4  2003        0        0        0        1        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0
5  2000        0        0        0        0        1        0        0        0        0        0        0        0
6  2001        0        0        0        0        0        1        0        0        0        0        0        0
7  2002        0        0        0        0        0        0        1        0        0        0        0        0
8  2003        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        1        0        0        0        0
9  2000        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        1        0        0        0
10 2001        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        1        0        0
11 2002        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        1        0
12 2003        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach with `dplyr::across`. We can make the final result into a plain data.frame with `purrr:invoke` as demonstrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65815796/13095326).

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
YearCountry %>% 
    mutate(across(AL:UK, ~ . * select(cur_data(), Y2000d:Y2003d))) %>%
    select(-(Y2000d:Y2003d)) %>% 
    invoke(.f = data.frame) %>%
    rename_with(~str_replace(.,"\\.",""))
   Time ALY2000d ALY2001d ALY2002d ALY2003d FRY2000d FRY2001d FRY2002d FRY2003d UKY2000d UKY2001d UKY2002d UKY2003d
1  2000         1         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
2  2001         0         1         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
3  2002         0         0         1         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
4  2003         0         0         0         1         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
5  2000         0         0         0         0         1         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
6  2001         0         0         0         0         0         1         0         0         0         0         0         0
7  2002         0         0         0         0         0         0         1         0         0         0         0         0
8  2003         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         1         0         0         0         0
9  2000         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         1         0         0         0
10 2001         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         1         0         0
11 2002         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         1         0
12 2003         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         1
```

Comment: This works but I think there is an issue with the column names because when I try to write this with library(haven) to a DTA-file (stata) I get the error "Error: Columns of type list not supported yet"

Comment: Using `purrr::invoke` should take care of the problem.

Comment: purrr installed but new error when writing with haven is : Error: Failed to create column `AL.Y2000d`: A provided name contains an illegal character. Is there a way to just remove all the "." from column names?

Comment: Sure, you can use `rename_with`. Check the edit.

Answer (score 2):

**1) model.matrix** We split the names by the number of characters in them (the countries have 2 characters in their names and the years have 6) and paste pluses in each. (Alternately use `Plus(grep("^..$", nms, value = TRUE))` to get the country names and use that in place of `spl["2"]` and similarly `Plus(grep("^Y....d$", nms, value = TRUE))` in place of `spl["6"]`.)

```
c(`2` = "AL+FR+UK", `6` = "Y2000d+Y2001d+Y2002d+Y2003d")
```

and from that the formula:

```
~(AL + FR + UK):(Y2000d + Y2001d + Y2002d + Y2003d) + 0
```

and then compute its model matrix.

The formula could also be expanded to one accepted by `lm` by modifying the `sprintf` format so we might not even need to create the model matrix.  For example, if we had a response vector `R` then we could write: `s <- sprintf("R ~ (%s)*(%s)", spl["2"], spl["4"]); fo <- formula(s); lm(fo, YearCountry)` to include all variables and the interactions of countries and year as well as an intercept.

```
Plus <- function(x) paste(x, collapse = "+")
nms <- names(YearCountry)[-1]
spl <- sapply(split(nms, nchar(nms)), Plus)

s <- sprintf("~ (%s):(%s)+0", spl["2"], spl["6"])
fo <- formula(s)

model.matrix(fo, YearCountry)
```

giving this matrix:

```
   AL:Y2000d AL:Y2001d AL:Y2002d AL:Y2003d FR:Y2000d FR:Y2001d FR:Y2002d FR:Y2003d UK:Y2000d UK:Y2001d UK:Y2002d UK:Y2003d
1          1         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
2          0         1         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
3          0         0         1         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
4          0         0         0         1         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
5          0         0         0         0         1         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
6          0         0         0         0         0         1         0         0         0         0         0         0
7          0         0         0         0         0         0         1         0         0         0         0         0
8          0         0         0         0         0         0         0         1         0         0         0         0
9          0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         1         0         0         0
10         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         1         0         0
11         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         1         0
12         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         1
attr(,"assign")
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
```

Alternately we can write it compactly like this:

```
Plus <- function(x) paste(x, collapse = "+")
nms <- names(YearCountry)
s <- sprintf("~ (%s):(%s)+0", Plus(nms[2:4]), Plus(nms[5:8]))
fo <- formula(s)
model.matrix(fo, YearCountry)
```

**2) eList** Another approach is to use list comprehensions.  With the eList package we can do this:

```
library(eList)
DF(for(i in YearCountry[2:4]) for(j in YearCountry[5:8]) i*j)
```

giving this data frame.  Use `as.matrix(...)` on it if you want a matrix.

```
   AL.Y2000d AL.Y2001d AL.Y2002d AL.Y2003d FR.Y2000d FR.Y2001d FR.Y2002d FR.Y2003d UK.Y2000d UK.Y2001d UK.Y2002d UK.Y2003d
1          1         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
2          0         1         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
3          0         0         1         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
4          0         0         0         1         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
5          0         0         0         0         1         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
6          0         0         0         0         0         1         0         0         0         0         0         0
7          0         0         0         0         0         0         1         0         0         0         0         0
8          0         0         0         0         0         0         0         1         0         0         0         0
9          0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         1         0         0         0
10         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         1         0         0
11         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         1         0
12         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         1
```

**3) listcompr** listcompr is another list comprehension package.  Note that the development version of this package is needed in order to use `bycol=`.  Replace `gen.named.matrix` with `gen.named.data.frame` if you want a data frame.

```
# devtools::github_github("patrickroocks/listcompr")
library(listcompr)

nms <- names(YearCountry)
gen.named.matrix("{nms[i]}.{nms[j]}", YearCountry[[i]] * YearCountry[[j]],
  i = 2:4, j = 5:8, bycol = TRUE)
```